# Library Dart Packages has broken classes path

Tags: android, flutter, dart

The Flutter project seems that the cache doesn't exist or what.
and it can't 'fit' in fact.
Someone who can do me a favor.
thanks
As below:
[image]

[image]

Comment: It would be nice if you could add what you have done before this happend.

Answer (score 3):

This is what fixed it for me. : "Remove Invalid Roots" in the Project Structure -> Problems

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try `dart pub cache repair`.  If you have an older dart install, just "pub cache repair", but be sure to break yourself of that habit soon.

Comment: Thank you. But 'dart pub cache repair' did not work.

Comment: bro did you solve this?? i'm having the same issue

Comment: me too out of the blue what a nightmare.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced this error.  It was caused by cache folders lacking a lib folder.  In my case, the folders were ios specific and did not contain a lib folder inside.
I simply added an empty lib folder to resolve.

Answer (score 0):

There is a package break your Android build if it or its dependencies aren't compatible with AndroidX.
See [AndroidX Migration](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/androidx-migration) for more information on the problem and how to fix it.

or

It may be due to the version of the package, so you may need to change the version only
[image: image of issue]

Answer (score 0):

This same problem happened to me, it came out right after I changed the **"GradleException"** to **"FileNotFoundException"**. in build.gradle...
there will be a code more or even so:

```
def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
       throw new **FileNotFoundException**("Flutter SDK not found. Set location with flutter.sdk in local.properties file.")
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: How to fix this issue ?